# Bayesian neural nets - Not able to get reasonable results with DenseVariational layers

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, bayesian, tensorflow

I am trying a regression problem with the following dataset (sinusoidal curve) of size `500`

[image: Dataset]

First, I tried with 2 dense layer with 10 units each

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='tanh'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='tanh'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1.))
    ])
```

Trained with negative log likelihood loss as follows

```py
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss=neg_log_likelihood)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=50)
```

Resulting plot
[image: Without uncertainty]

Next, I tried similar environment with `DenseVariational`

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            10, activation='tanh', make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            make_prior_fn=prior, kl_weight=1/N, kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            10, activation='tanh', make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            make_prior_fn=prior, kl_weight=1/N, kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            1, activation='tanh', make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            make_prior_fn=prior, kl_weight=1/N, kl_use_exact=True),
        tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1.))
    ])
```

As the number of parameters approximately double with this, I have tried increasing dataset size and/or epoch size up to 100 times with no success. Results are usually as follows.

[image: With uncertainty]

My questions is how do I get comparable results as that of `Dense` layer with `DenseVariational`? I have also read that it can be sensitive to initial values. [Here](https://github.com/vmg27/bayes-by-backprop/blob/main/bayes_by_backprop.py) is the link to full code. Any suggestions are welcome.

Edit:
After shimao's suggestion in comments. I tried to widen the prior with standard deviation varying up to 10. It did induce more non-linearity, though far from perfect. Below is the plot
[image: Widen prior]

Comment: have you tried widening out your prior?

Comment: @shimao Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it and added an edit to the question.